# Mongodb C# driver - convert aggregate project ROOT

Tags: c#, mongodb

is there a way to convert mongodb aggregate:

```
{
    $project: {
        custom_field: "$obj.obj_field1",
        document: "$$ROOT"
    }
},
```

using the C# driver

Comment: As I know, driver supports aggregate operations. What is your problem?

Comment: I can't make the '$$ROOT' operation.

Comment: Give more details please. Try to write what your already tried and what problems did you faced

Comment: Well I was writing the find section, and the project section and got results, but I want to return the "root" of my results, I know it possible with aggregate on mongodb, but I didn't find anything similar on mongodb c# drive

Comment: You have several builders for each section of aggregate request in c#. There are Bson... where you can write options like in mongodb shell. I can't test it just now but it should work.